# Tableview forms need to have keyboard appearing raise view when textfield is at the bottom but not when user scrolls so it is at the top

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I need to make a form that is long, which entails having certain textFields either at the top or bottom depending on the user's behavior. When the textfield is tapped near the bottom, I have to raise the view. However, when that textField is at the top of the screen, the view needs to not be raised or it pushes the textField off the screen. I can't find anything online that addresses this problem besides third parties (where you lose control of the design usually).

Comment: Are you using a `UITableViewController`? Or are you using a `UIScrollView`? Neither?

Comment: UITableView as part of a normal UIViewController

Answer (score 1):

Have you looked at [IQKeyboardManagerSwift](https://github.com/hackiftekhar/IQKeyboardManager), you need not write any code nor any setup required and it does not impact your design.